# programmatically trigger onDrop function of react dropzone

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm using react dropzone and I need to trigger the onDrop function programmatically when files sent as prop from another component. I have tried ref but this only exposes the open function.

```
<Dropzone
  multiple={true}
  accept={['application/pdf']}
  onDrop={files =>
    this.handleDrop(files, setFieldValue, setSubmitting)
  }
>
  {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
    <div
      {...getRootProps()}
      className="drop-border"
    >
      <input
        {...getInputProps()}
      />
      <div>
        Drop a pdf document here or click to select one
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
</Dropzone>
```

Comment: Can you show a piece of code? In general, the onDrop is sent to you via `getRootProps` of react-dropzone but I can help more if you show the code

Comment: @NNH i have added the piece of code.

Comment: Since you are getting the files as props, can't you use a local state ?? And set the local state initial value to the props value and then handle it on drop.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call it e.g.:

```
componentDidUpdate({ files }) {
    if(files != this.props.files) {
        this.handleDrop(this.props.files, setFieldValue, setSubmitting)
    }
}
```

? Do you need the component `onDrop`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const uploaderProps = getRootProps();
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.items.add(initialFile);
const event = new DragEvent("drop", {
   bubbles: true,
   cancelable: true,
   dataTransfer,
});
event.persist = () => {};
uploaderProps.onDrop(event)
```